# How to change the blue line below the text field in android

Tags: android, textbox, border, textfield

Can I change the color of the blue line that appears below the text field in android?? If yes then how can I do it? Please help.

Comment: can you show some screenshot ?

Answer (score -1):

That was not the color it was the image which was used by default

I guess the only solution is to prepare the image by yourself

[Create Android Default UI with your own colors](http://www.android-holo-colors.com/)

Comment: This takes me to a weird page that tries to install an extension in the browser..